# MSBuild define logfile in project

Tags: .net, msbuild

I'm wondering if it's possible to define a logging output in a msbuild project file?
I'm aware of the command line switch /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=MyLog.log
My build process is started from a separate build.proj that includes other VS project files.

I would like to get rid of the command line option and place it in the build file.

Thanks in advance

Chris

Comment: you mean Visual Studio project file?

Comment: No sorry. I forgot to mention. I meant that I have a seperate build file that includes other VS project files. I'd like to have to output of my isolated build file written to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, neither are great:

1. Run MSBuild from within your build.proj file using the Exec task rather than using the MSBuild task.
2. Create a default response file named MSBuild.rsp containing the logger parameters and place it beside MSBuild.exe.  This will affect every build, not just that one project.